# Typescript promise generic type

Tags: generics, typescript

I've a sample Promise function like below. On success I return a `number` and on false I return `string`. The compiler is complaining to specify some kind of generic type to the promise. In this case what type I've to specify? Do I've to specify like `Promise<number>` or `Promise<number | string>`?

```
function test(arg: string): Promise {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (arg === "a") {
            resolve(1);
        } else {
            reject("1");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Did you try `Promise<number|string>`?

Comment: It don't complains by doing that. Is that the right thing to do? Is it ok to specify both the types of resolve and reject?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

The generic type of the Promise should correspond to the non-error return-type of the function. The error is implicitly of type `any` and is not specified in the Promise generic type.

So for example:

```
function test(arg: string): Promise<number> {
    return new Promise<number>((resolve, reject) => {
        if (arg === "a") {
            resolve(1);
        } else {
            reject("1");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to specify the type of the error case? E.g. I have a promise which, if rejects, rejects with a custom object. Can I specify the type of the rejection value using `Promise<T>` builtin generic type? Thank you!

Comment: @tonix For the exact reason that you are rejecting with a custom object (the flexibility to do so) is because `Promise` has `any` error type. The error type can't be constrained because any running code within the promise can throw anything, not just normal `Error`. (See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw . It's `throw expression`). Since the promise is a generic object which can't control what runs inside it, and it would also be tedious/over-expectant to expect you (the dev) to control what runs inside it, the error type can't be constrained.

Comment: @GeorgePantazes : I'm not convinced that it would be tedious if one could *optionally* specify the reject type. Also, one can't control what runs inside for a resolved value either, but still one can specify it.

Comment: @BrettZamir a relevant answer to tonix's question is here (also has a link to an elaboration about TS's type checker): https://stackoverflow.com/a/50071254/6103242. 

As I got it, the reason why Error's type can't be constrained is because the type checker in general can't differentiate the types of what's been thrown. That is, it can enforce a type of a returning value, but it **can not** enforce the type of a thrown value (whether in promises or not – consider a catch statement in TS).

Answer (score 6):

You could define a custom Promise type that actually also cares about the type of the rejection. You can also just give it a single type and the reject type will be `any`, like in a normal promise.

```js
type CustomPromise<T, F = any> = {
    catch<TResult = never>(
        onrejected?: ((reason: F) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>) | undefined | null
    ): Promise<T | TResult>;
} & Promise<T>;

function test(arg: string): CustomPromise<number, string> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (arg === "a") {
            resolve(1);
        } else {
            reject("1");
        }
    });
}

const myPromise = test("a");
myPromise.then((value) => {}); //value is of type `number`
myPromise.catch((reason) => {}); //reason is of type `string`
```

Comment: Excellent. I am going to be using this `FullyTypedPromise` now.

Answer (score -1):

```
function test(arg: string) {
   return new Promise((resolve: (value: number) => void, reject) => {
    if (arg === "a") {
        resolve(1);
    } else {
        reject("1");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Code only answers can generally be improved by adding some explanation of how and why they work. This is even more important when adding an answer to an older question with an accepted answer. Point out what new aspect of the question your answer addresses and note if the passage of time and introduction of new versions impacts the answer.