# Correctly Typing Return Value of Async Fetch Functions

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, return-value

The flow of an asynchronous function in Javascript requires typing such a workflow in Typescript as **multiple possible return values**. My main question is whether or not this is necessary and best practice.

If all goes well, the function returns my desired value. If it doesn't go well, I may want to throw an error.

But if I throw an error, that doesn't communicate the return value of the function, and so I still need to inform typescript what value the function should return.

**So we start that code that looks a bit like this example:**

```
class PostsClient {

   public async fetchPosts(): Promise<Posts[]> {
     try {
        const posts: Posts[] = await this.httpClient.fetch(this.apiUrl);
        return posts;
     } catch (e) {
        this.logger.captureError(e);
        throw e;
     }
   }

}

// Error from Typescript: `Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.`
```

---

In response to the warning from Typescript we **change the return value of the function** to `Promise<Posts[] | undefined>`

My hope would be that using this function inside another caller, for example a layout controller, could communicate with the typescript engine that the only reason that this function would not return the desired type `Posts[]` would be if an error is thrown, and the control flow of the function would be interrupted anyways.

But instead one ends up having problems like this.

```
class PostLayoutController {

    public async fetchAndStorePosts(): void {
       const posts = await this.postsClient.fetchPosts();
        this.sendAnalyticsData(posts)  // ERROR -- posts could be undefined!
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    }
}
```

Is it correct to deal with this by simply using a return statement to prevent further logic from executing?

```
if (!posts) {
   return;
}
```

or is there some better solution to this?

Comment: `posts` *won't* be undefined there - if `fetchPosts` throws an error, the call to `sendAnalyticsData` never gets reached. The error type is implicitly `any`; see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/41079355/3001761.

Answer (score 0):

As @jonrsharpe mentioned in a comment to my question, Typescript actually does recognize that the `fetchPosts` function throws an error.

My problem was that in the actual implementation, we were using a `handleApiErrors` function which didn't have a recognizable 'error throwing' signature for Typescript, so it assumed the execution flow would continue.

This was an example of how the actual code was implemented:

```
class PostLayoutController {

    public async fetchAndStorePosts(): void {
       try {
          const posts = await this.postsClient.fetchPosts();
          this.storePosts(posts);
       } catch (e) {
          this.handleApiErrors(e);
       }
    }


    private handleApiErrors(e: Error) {
       if (e.code === 400) {
          throw new InvalidSubmissionError(e.message, ...more props)
       }

       // Some other error class cases.

       throw e;
    }
}
```

So I see that I need to do the error logic in the catch block and not delegate it to another function in order for Typescript to understand what is going on.